# Summary status of a group of hosts in Centreon

Tags: centreon-api

It may be a stupid question when you know Centron, but I'm very new to it.

I'm trying to determine if it is possible, with Centreon, to do the following:

1. Create a group of hosts (OK for me)
2. Have a service for each host with a simple check (e.g. ping) (OK for me)
3. Have a service or anything else that will tell me the summary status of this group (??)

By summary, I mean something like:

- x% of hosts are OK, y% are Warning, z% are Critical

or

- group status (OK, warning, critical) depending on thresholds

I have this very specific need and I need to know whether I can achieve it with Centreon (version 2.8.2 for now).

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

That's not a stupid question at all :) You can have that kind of information in multiple ways.

I guess in your case the simplest one would be to use 
the Global Health widget (https://github.com/centreon/centreon-widget-global-health).

If you have standard Centreon repository installed, just do a

```
yum install centreon-widget-global-health
```

Then you go to Administration > Extension > Widget and you install it from the interface.

--

If you need to go a bit further in data visualization or aggregated indicators, you may want to have a look to some Graphical (drawing) capabilities of Centreon ([quick start here](https://docs.centreon.com/current/en/getting-started/create-graphical-view.html)) or [Service Mapping capabilities](https://docs.centreon.com/current/en/getting-started/model-it-services.html).

Disclaimer: these two last solution are part of Centreon Commercial license.

To finish, I recommand you update your version, the current one is 20.04, the 2.8.x is not supported anymore.

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own scripts, if you're feeling adventurous, using the REST API for querying live statuses (combined with CLAPI for submitting configurations), and execute said scripts as normal Centreon checks.

REST API: https://docs-api.centreon.com/api/centreon-web/

CLAPI: https://docs.centreon.com/docs/api/clapi/

Otherwise, I know of only one centreon tool that can do what you want out of the box, that is the "Business Activities" tool. It allows you aggregate many hosts into a "Business Unit" or a "Cluster" and define metrics and notification triggers for the cluster, exactly like the ones you mentioned. But it's a PAID feature.

If you don't mind using external tools, you might want to export your data into a separate visualization tool like Grafana. Once you've collected your metrics into Grafana, you can run calculations on them and setup notifications. It's a pretty popular setup these days to use Centreon/Nagios/Prometheus as the data collection engine, and export the data via "connectors", or to simply query the Centreon Database for the data you need. But to be fair, this is not considered beginner stuff because you have to know the schema of Centreon Databases in order to query the database.